# How to partially change table entries in mysql

Tags: mysql

Table "media" has few columns; column "url" has values like `"http://10.10.10.10/media/may20/recording1.mp4"`. There are about 1000 entries. How can I change `10.10.10.10 to 11.11.11.11` leaving everything else the same?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)
function

```
UPDATE media SET URL = Replace(URL, '://10.10.10.10', '://11.11.11.11')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way also

```
UPDATE media 
SET url = REPLACE(url, 'http://10.10.10.10', 'http://11.11.11.11')
WHERE url LIKE ('http://10.10.10.10%');
```

relevant docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace